# How to assign external IP address to running service?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have the following service:

```
NAME      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
rancher   ClusterIP   10.245.162.197   <none>        80/TCP    10h
```

that I would like to assign an **EXTERNAL-IP** to it. I tried:

```
kubectl expose deployment rancher --type=LoadBalancer --name=rancher-access
```

but the **EXTERNAL-IP** does not still get assigned. I am using Digital Ocean Kubernetes.
How to get an **EXTERNAL-IP** for `rancher` service.

Comment: You set the name of the service to `rancher-access`, check that one.

Comment: `kubectl expose deployment rancher --type=LoadBalancer --name=rancher` it shows: Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "rancher" already exists

Comment: Yes, it exists, you can see it up above. If you want to edit that one use `kubectl edit`.

Comment: Could you please show it to me, how to do it?

Comment: Just run `kubectl get service rancher-access` and include the output above.

Comment: Sorry, which output above do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211534/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-coderanger).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. The LoadBalancer type of service is implemented by adding code to the kubernetes master specific to each cloud provider. There isn't a cloud provider for Digital Ocean [supported cloud providers](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/providers.go), so the LoadBalancer type will not be able to take advantage of Digital Ocean's Floating IPs.

Instead, you should consider using a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) service or attaching an [ExternalIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) to your service and mapping the exposed IP to a Digital Ocean's floating IP.

To get the actual IP you need to expose you need to ssh into your gateway droplet and find its anchor IP by hitting up the metadata service:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/interfaces/public/0/anchor_ipv4/address
```

2. Use Digital Ocean created [cloud provider implementation](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager#kubernetes-cloud-controller-manager-for-digitalocean)
3. You could use an NGINX ingress controller and point a DigitalOcean LB to the host where the controller is deployed. With some more tinkering you could probably make this a highly available setup

https://github.com/hobby-kube/guide#bringing-traffic-to-the-cluster

Comment: How to create such as External IP?

Comment: You need to create a gateway and then use the command in answer to get the IP https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/vpc/resources/droplet-as-gateway/